# axios use of data server argument

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to axios to contact a remote server
If I used the following format, my server never seems to parse the data arguments

```
axios({
    url: API_URL + 'oauth/token',
    method:'post',
    data: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password,
        scope: 'webclient'
          },
    auth: {
        username: 'foo',
        password: 'foobar'
    },
    responseType: 'json'
  })
```

But if I use the vulgar format

```
axios({
    url: API_URL + 'oauth/token',
    method: 'post',
       data:'grant_type=password&username='+user.username+'&password='+user.password+'&scope=webclient',
    auth: {
        username: 'foo',
        password: 'foobar'
    },
    responseType: 'json'
  })
```

Every works as expected, so can anybody tell me what the difference is between the two different forms of the data argument?

Comment: What are you expecting on your server? formdata or json

Comment: I see what your suggesting, using the data:{ blah format does not define the data exchange type, while using the &fee=bar&fie=bar&foo=bar assumes a url format type.  
So all I need to do is define a content-type and it should work ?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an object to `data` then Axios will encode it as JSON, not URL Form Encoded data (which is what your manual encoding uses and thus, presumably, what your server expects).

[The documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) has several examples of form encoding data programmatically:

> ```
> const params = new URLSearchParams();
> params.append('param1', 'value1');
> params.append('param2', 'value2');
> axios.post('/foo', params);
> ```

Make sure you also set `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` as the `Content-Type` request header.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by both previous answers, the issue is the type of data the server is prepared to accept, with out setting a Content-Type, axious defaults to Json.

In my case my server is configure to accept URL encode style connection.  Sending it as a 'data' object is invalid, it most be sent using params.  Since I am not sending any data using data: it seems that axios decides that it can remove any attempt by myself to set a Content-Type.

I am using the following code that removes that vulgar data set up

```
url: API_URL + 'oauth/token',
    method:'post',
       params: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password,
        scope: 'webclient'
          },
    auth: {
        username:'foo',
        password:'foobar'
    },
    responseType:'json',
  })
```